# In Django update-view instance is not pre-filled in the form

Tags: django

Update-form is not filled in with the instance of the object: when I press the the button that leads me to the update-view page it has no data, however if I copy the url while being on that page and pass it to a new tab - it immediately has the data.

Check the code:

Model:

```
class ExpenseName(Time):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    budget_default = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Backend:

```
@login_required
def update_expense(request, id):
    item = ExpenseName.objects.get(id=id)
    if item.user == request.user:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = NewFieldForm(request.POST, instance=item)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = NewFieldForm(instance=item)
    else:
        raise Http404('You are not allowed to see this')

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'expenses/update.html', context)
```

Path

```
path('<int:id>/update/', update_expense, name='update-field')
```

URL

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'update-field' item.id %}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
             <button id="my-button2"  type="submit"></button>
 </form>
```

So, if I click on the button above I get to the page with this url -http://127.0.0.1:8000/expenses/9/update/, however when clicking the button and getting to the page there is not data prefilled. If I while being on that same page copy this http://127.0.0.1:8000/expenses/9/update/ and pass it to another tab - it prefills immediately.

Frontend:

```
{% extends 'expenses/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<div class="row h-100  align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-6 text-center" style="height:250px; width: 100px; padding-top: 30px; background-color: #4db8ff; border-radius: 10px;">
    <form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
        Name of the expense:<div>{{ form.name }}</div>
        Budget: <div>{{ form.budget_default }}</div>
            <div><button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark mt-2 text-center" type="submit">Update</button></div>
            <a class="text-dark" style="font-size: 13px;" href="{% url 'home' %}">Cancel</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Form:

```
class NewFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExpenseName
        fields = [
            'name',
            'budget_default'
        ]

        labels = {
            'name': '',
            'budget_default': '',
        }
```

I really do hope someone can help me understand what the issue is. Can't complete the project without solving it.

Comment: Could you put the code for the form as well?

Comment: Added the form, hope ti helps!

Comment: Can you do a print(id) in your view, then access it and see if it is being passed properly.

Comment: Just did it. It printed the correct id in the terminal - 9, then I accessed the update page with it and it works. As it gets filled upon refresh, it means the ID passes to it for sure. If needed, the link on a button is like that `{% url 'update-field' item.id %}` of course with form tags

Comment: So if I am understanding it right, when you first go to the page there is nothing but a refresh fixes it? And the url does not change.

Comment: Look, I just copied the full url and inserted it into a new tab and the data rendered immediately without the refresh.
The full url is like that "http://127.0.0.1:8000/expenses/9/update/".  If you want you can try yourself, I have it online here https://xgrigoriy1992x.pythonanywhere.com/expenses/

Comment: When I refresh I still get nothing.

Comment: Did you create the expense and then click the "pencil" icon to go to the update-view? If so, no data should be rendered as per my experience. Then click on url and press enter, or copy it and pass it to a different tab. it will work (at least it does for me)

Comment: Oh weird. Yeah the copying makes it fill out lol.

Comment: So, any suggestions?...))) That is the mystery of this bug.

Comment: So it seems you would still need to pass initial value to the field as the instance does not do that for you. When making the form in your get do something like this. form = NewFieldForm(instance=item, initial={'name': item.name})

Comment: That isn't the issue since passing the instance should do that for you already.

Comment: I just removed the instance from the view and did everything we did : copied the url and passed it to a different tab. Without the instance the information did not get filled. (done locally, not on the server)

Comment: Edwin Cruz, if you are here. The problem was that the button that led to the update view page was within the form tags, even though it wasnt the form... lol. It was supposed to be a link only. Problem solved.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!